# Ubuntu Desktop Not Loading Correctly After 16.04

Tags: command-line, 15.10, 16.04, do-release-upgrade

I recently upgraded my system from 15.10 to 16.04 using the `do-release-upgrade` command. The upgrade failed for an unknown reason and now the Ubuntu Desktop does not load. I get my desktop wallpaper and my icons but nothing else. It is however detecting both my monitors correctly. I'm guessing that there is a package that needs to be updated since the command line states 16.04 but the login screen still states 15.10. Does anyone have an idea how to rectify the issue?

Jake

Comment: @k-five Can you by chance remember the last step... Looks like the answer was removed :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't uncommon with Ubuntu and seems to plague LTS releases worse than regulars for some reason.  The failing upgrade will cause things to get stuck halfway between releases, and you need to kick it in the shin to get it going again.

Assuming you can get a command prompt on the system (CTRL-ALT-F1) and login as yourself, try the following things:

First set ownership on your home directory.  Doubt that's the cause, but I've had it happen before:

```
sudo chown -R yourlogin:yourlogin /home/yourlogin
```

Next, try to finish the apt upgrade process:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If that errors, try running:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

And a last resort, force remaining package installs:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

And finally, clean up leftovers with:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```